# Shapefiles import to Matlab incomplete

Tags: matlab, gis, shapefile

I am trying to use the readshape function in Matlab to load a shapefile (.shp) into matlab. The shapefile contains 29xx point features, and has been confirmed in ArcGIS to not be corrupted. When I load the shape file into Matlab only 23xx features are imported to the structure array.

The portion of the shapefile that is lost is a section out of the middle of study area. What would cause this and what is a potential work around?

The points indicate the centroid of a fishnet across the study area. The strip across the middle should be filled with points.

[image: The points indicate the centroid of a fishnet across the study area. The strip across the middle should be filled with points.]

Comment: Can you join the shapefile ? We need to reproduce the problem.